# dataframe.show creates class cast exception spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2. df1 is created from avro file using spark avro api. df2 is created using hive context. I am joining df1 and df2 like below,

```
var df = df1.join(df2,Seq("column"),"right_outer").drop(df1("column"))
```

However when I tried to print using df.show() it throws class cast exception (String cannot be type cast to double). However df1.show() and df2.show() works fine.

I even tried removing null values using,

```
df = df.na.fill(0)
```

But still I am facing same error.

Comment: Can you say something about the schema of `df1` and `df2`? Has `column` the same data type in `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: @R1tschY the type of column is Int in df1 and Float in df2